# Why won't barchart in Pandas stack different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-munging

Using Pandas, python 3. Working in jupyter.

Ive made this graph below using the following code:

```
temp3 = pd.crosstab(df['Credit_History'], df['Loan_Status']) 
temp3.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, color = ['red', 'blue'], grid = False)
print(temp3)
```

[image: Stacked Bars]

And then tried to do the same, but with divisions for Gender. I wanted to make this:
[image: Four Bars]

So I wrote this code:
[image]

And made this monstrosity. I'm unfamiliar with pivot tables in pandas, and after reading documentation, am still confused. I'm assuming that `aggfunc` affects the values given, but not the indices. How can I separate the loan status so that it reads as different colors for 'Y' and 'N'?

Trying a method similar to the methods used for `temp3` simply yields a key error:

```
temp3x = pd.crosstab(df['Credit_History'], df['Loan_Status', 'Gender']) 
temp3x.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, color = ['red', 'blue'], grid = False)
print(temp3)
```

How can I make the 'Y' and 'N' appear separately as they are in the first graph, but for all 4 bars instead of using just 2 bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a new column called `Loan_status_word` and then pivot.

```
loan_status_word = loan_status.map({0:'No', 1:'Yes'})
df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status', 
               index=['Credit_History', 'Gender'], 
               columns = 'loan_status_word', 
               aggfunc ='size')
```

Comment: This almost works! I still need to be able to count the Y/N separately, and not sure how to go about doing that; with the current aggfunc I have, it just lumps them all together, which isn't what I'm aiming for. How would I be able to separate the Y/N entries into separate counts?

Answer (score 1):

Try to format your data such that each item you want in your legend is in a single column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [3, 1],
        [4, 1],
        [1, 4],
        [1, 3]
    ], 
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([(1, 0), list('MF')], names=['Credit', 'Gendeer']),
    pd.Index(['Yes', 'No'], name='Loan Status')
)
df
```

[image]

---

Then you can plot

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but how can I go about transforming my dataset to a dataframe in the order you suggested? I follow what you're saying, but don't understand how I would apply the concept to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to achieve the desired result:

```
temp4=pd.crosstab([df['Credit_History'],df['Gender']],df['Loan_Status'])
temp4.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,color=['red','blue'],grid=False)
```